# How to make my menu links clickable

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the following page: http://pastebin.com/sJAN1jkk which contains a dropdown navigation menu, consisting of several unordered lists.

The dropdown part of the menu, works without issue, the problem is, that when clicking any links within these lists, nothing happens.

I have a feeling it's down to the javascript somewhere, but not being an expert, I'm at a loss to explain why.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

If I've missed any relevant/needed info, please let me know, and I will update the question.

----Edit----

Menu HTML:

```
<div class="rotaWrapper">
    <div id="ddRotas" class="wrapper-dropdown-rotas" tabindex="1">
        <span id="lblRotasMenu">Rotas and absences</span>
        <ul class="dropdown">
            <li><a id="hypRotas" href="Rotas.aspx">Rotas</a></li>
            <li><a id="hypAbsence" href="Absence.aspx">Absences</a></li>
            <li><a id="hypTraining" href="Training.aspx">Training</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

            function DropDown(el) {
                this.dd = el;
                this.initEvents();
            }
            DropDown.prototype = {
                initEvents : function() {
                    var obj = this;

                    obj.dd.on('click', function(event){
                        $(this).toggleClass('active');
                        return false;
                    });
                },
            }

            $(function() {

                var ddRotas = new DropDown( $('#ddRotas') );
                var ddWages = new DropDown( $('#ddWages') );
                var ddMessages = new DropDown( $('#ddMessages') );
                var ddDocs = new DropDown( $('#ddDocs') );
                var ddAdmin = new DropDown( $('#ddAdmin') );

                $(document).click(function() {
                    // all dropdowns
                    $('.wrapper-dropdown-rotas').removeClass('active');
                    $('.wrapper-dropdown-wages').removeClass('active');
                    $('.wrapper-dropdown-docs').removeClass('active');
                    $('.wrapper-dropdown-messages').removeClass('active');
                    $('.wrapper-dropdown-admin').removeClass('active');
                });

            });

        </script>
```

Comment: Please add meaningful code and a problem description here. Don't just link 
to pastebin. Posting a 
[Short, Self Contained, Correct Example (SSCCE)](http://www.sscce.org/) 
that demonstrates your problem would help you get better answers. For more info, 
see [Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to
it?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/) Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this might be your problem:

```
obj.dd.on('click', function(event){
    $(this).toggleClass('active');
    return false;
});
```

You are capturing all click events for your dropdown and then returning `false`. This stops the click event from firing.

Comment: I see, changing it to true, stops the dropdown from dropping down.

Comment: You need to more specific in your selector. You need to change the way the code works so that the click event only fires when you click on the menu item (I assume `<span id="lblRotasMenu">Rotas and absences</span>` in this case) and not one of the items in your list.

Comment: Much appreciated, I'll have a look once I'm back in front of a PC.